# Mongodb finding results from sessions collection by custom id

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am using the Mongojs library which is thin wrapper around mongodb library. I want to do some find queries in sessions collections, this means that I use mongo to store sessions(connect-mongo).

The problem is that

```
db.sessions.find({}, cb); -- returns all the sessions
```

When I try to find specify session by the id which is taken from req.sessionID - string, this returns **null** all time.

```
db.sessions.findOne({ _id: req.sessionID }, cb); -- yes the seesionId exists, when i execute this query manually it works
```

Also tried the 'mongodb' library to connect directly.

```
var Db = require('mongodb').Db,
    MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient,
    Server = require('mongodb').Server,
    ReplSetServers = require('mongodb').ReplSetServers,
    ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID,
    Binary = require('mongodb').Binary,
    GridStore = require('mongodb').GridStore,
    Code = require('mongodb').Code,
    BSON = require('mongodb').pure().BSON,
    assert = require('assert');

var db = new Db(session.db, new Server(session.host, session.port,
 {auto_reconnect: false, poolSize: 4}), {w:0, native_parser: false});

function findBySid(sid, cb) {

    db.close();
    db.open(function(err, db) {

        db.collection('sessions').findOne({ _id: sid }, function(err, session) {

                cb(err, session);

        });
    })
```

The structure itself looks like this and is created by the connect-mongo

```
> db.sessions.find({ _id: 'QFtHqaTdtg5kucwvBmY3BZ7m' }).pretty()
{
    "_id" : "QFtHqaTdtg5kucwvBmY3BZ7m",
    "session" : "{\"cookie\":{\"originalMaxAge\":null,\"expires\":null,\"httpOnly\":true,\"domain\":\"asad.\",\"path\":\"/\"}}",
    "expires" : ISODate("2013-08-12T12:34:49.271Z")
}
```

Comment: Try like `.findOne({_id: new BSON.ObjectID(sid)}),`

Comment: I can not use the ObjectID because the session id custom string not mongo generated value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually Mongo document saves as

```
 { "_id" : ObjectId("51ecdea131ce0986e06e91fe"),....}
```

so you have to find out like below

```
db.newcol.find({_id:ObjectId("51ecdea131ce0986e06e91fe")});
```

Following shell output will explain.

```
 >db.newcol.find({_id:51ecdea131ce0986e06e91fe});
  Mon Jul 29 18:25:54.563 JavaScript execution failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
 > db.newcol.find({_id:"51ecdea131ce0986e06e91fe"}); //No output empty
 > db.newcol.find({_id:ObjectId("51ecdea131ce0986e06e91fe")});
 { "_id" : ObjectId("51ecdea131ce0986e06e91fe"), "name" : "karthick.k", "email" :         "karthdfgdf@gmail.com", "phone_no" : "6666666666" }
```

So construct your query accordingly.

Comment: You are correct, but looking at the source code of https://github.com/kcbanner/connect-mongo/blob/master/lib/connect-mongo.js and you see that the _id is simple session id string

Comment: added the session structure and how this should work in shell

Comment: Yes understood. So have to console.log the `sid` to cross check the sid string

Comment: Yes there where problem elsewhere, the find procedure started too early as mongo was not filled with session data.